# How to set text by date and increment loop android?

Tags: java, android

I want to set text by date and incrementing loop, and when the day changes looping start from the beginning.

**Example**

```
1. day 1 =
   a. nameFile 110920190001
   b. nameFile 110920190002, etc.

2. day 2 =
   a. nameFile 120920190001
   b. nameFile 120920190002, etc.
```

**Code**

```
Date documentsDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat documentDates = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
String setTitleDocument = documentDates.format(documentsDate);       

for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    String countDocument = String.format("%04d", i);
    textNameDocument.setText("Document " + setTitleDocument + countDocument);
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just put the Date Initialization in the for loop for it to always take the new Instance of the date.**

```
public static void replace(String s) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        Date documentsDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat documentDates = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
        String setTitleDocument = documentDates.format(documentsDate);
        String countDocument = String.format("%04d", i);
        textNameDocument.setText("Document " + setTitleDocument + countDocument);
    }
}
```